# next redirects/rewrite with static generation

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there a way to use redirect or rewrite statically?

I have a blog (deployed on github pages), and I have already shared the link of posts on other places, the thing is, I want to change it from `myblog.com/post/slug-here`
to `myblog.com/a/:slug-here` and that's gonna break the old links i've already shared

Using the `redirects()` on `next.config.js` would be perfect, but on the docs it says that only works on Node.js environments

I also tried the `rewrites()`

```js
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      fallback: [
        {
          source: '/post/:slug',
          destination: '/a/:slug',
        },
      ],
    };
```

(because the docs doesn't say anything about only for Node.js environments) but without luck that also didn't worked. I think the only diference between them is that `rewrites()` "mask" the URL to make it appear that the URL haven't changed

just in case i'm missing something: it works on `yarn dev` but not  in production.

how could I achieve that statically generating?

Comment: Are you using `next export` to deploy the blog to GitHub Pages?

Comment: yes, as far as I know gh pages doesn't support the Node.js environment

Comment: Both `redirects` and `rewrites` require a running a server, and as such are not supported by `next export`.